# How to display a form from another thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, forms

I am running this code in a seperate thread on my C# Winforms app (the name of my form is MainForm):

```
DisplayDownload form2 = new DisplayDownload();

form2.TopMost = true;  
form2.Show();
```

But when the thread is launched, the form never opens.  If I move the code onto the main thread of my app, it opens fine, but if I launch it as it's own thread, the form never opens.

I tried using the accepted answer from this post:  [Calling a windows form from another thread (.Net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947476/calling-a-windows-form-from-another-thread-net) but I get this error:

Cannot convert anonymous method to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type

Here is the code I am trying to utilize:

```
MainForm.Invoke(delegate {
         DisplayDownload form2 = new DisplayDownload();


         form2.TopMost = true; 
         form2.Show();
});
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong and how to get it to work?

Comment: You should probably call `BeginInvoke()`, which doesn't wait for the method to finish running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `new MethodInvoker(delegate()`, So:

```
MainForm.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() 
{
             DisplayDownload form2 = new DisplayDownload();


             form2.TopMost = true; 
             form2.Show();
}));
```

Comment: This gets the same error when I pasted into my code:  "Cannot convert anonymous method to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type"

Comment: this time I forget to add new MethodInvoker :)

Comment: I get this error when trying to use the new updated/revised code:  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(System.Delegate)'

Comment: I tried the code my self, create `Form1` and `Form2` and add a button1 to `Form1`, when button1 click I run the `Form2` using this code and everything is running fine. However What is `MainForm`? I assumed you are referring to the current form "so in that case it will be replaced by `this` keyword" right?

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly instantiate a delegate type:

```
MainForm.Invoke(new Action(delegate { ... }));
```

C# 2 and later can implicitly convert method groups to delegates, but only to a specific delegate type.
The `Invoke` method takes the base `Delegate` class, so there is no specific delegate type for the compiler to create.
Therefore, you need to explicitly create a delegate yourself.

Comment: I get this error when adding that to my code: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(System.Delegate)'.  I added that line of code and put my code in place of the "...". Is that correct?

Comment: @fra: You need to get the existing instance of the `MainForm` class.

Answer (score 0):

Which thread do you want to handle events for the new Form?  If you want the main thread to handle events, then use `Control.Invoke` as the existing examples suggest.

If you want the new thread to manage its own UI events, then you need to call `Application.Run`.  When you do that, the form will be able to paint itself and will become visible on the screen.

Comment: @SLaks: There are situations where they're appropriate, and we haven't been given enough information to determine whether this is one of them, so I present both options.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //This is for WPF Application 
     try
       {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { 
         DisplayDownload form2 = new DisplayDownload();
         form2.TopMost = true; 
         form2.Show();
        }));
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
         }
```