# Show Form Message using non-Main UI Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms, websocket, notifications

I have a project that without usign any form/button or nothing like that, connects with a Websocket and using async methods receives some message(on a form created by myself) that is supposed to appear on the top-right corner of the screen.

But this message can appear from time to time (2 or 3 minutes) on the screen if the websocket doesn't say that it must stop. And this message can be big enough, that in order to make it look better I make my message appear in more than one form.

It causes an impression that it's a notification. So my class that connects with the websocket and receives the message async, calls another class using a thread that is a controller. The purpose of the controller is from time to time, show that message in various new form() notifications and obviously don't do it if the websocket doesn't return any message.

But when i call the form.show the program stops working.
I've looked around stackoverflow already, but the ideas that i've found didn't seem to work.

Some say that I should use invoke, but it kept giving error saying that 
"Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created", tried to solve like this: [C# calling form.show() from another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11995466/c-sharp-calling-form-show-from-another-thread) but it didn't work.

Some said that I should use .showDialog instead of .show, but it doesn't appear to be good, because it waits the window to be closed to terminate the method and as I said I need to open more than one notification at the same time.

Some said that the form was open with .show, but it was open for a very little period of time. But i couldn't notice if that was the case and even if it was i couldn't solve it. Well, what matter is that i'm stuck and i don't know what to do more.

Edited with Code:

```
//Main
Application.Run(new SocketService());

//SocketService class
        public SocketService()
        {
            alerta = null;

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine("Nome do Usúario:" + Environment.UserName);
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    Connect("ws://192.168.120.38:9091").Wait();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }
            }
        }

        public static async Task Connect(string uri)
        {
            ClientWebSocket webSocket = null;

            try
            {
                webSocket = new ClientWebSocket();
                await webSocket.ConnectAsync(new Uri(uri), CancellationToken.None);
                await Login(webSocket);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (webSocket != null)
                    webSocket.Dispose();

                lock (consoleLock)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("WebSocket closed.");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                }
            }
        }

        private static async Task Login(ClientWebSocket webSocket)
        {
            ArraySegment<Byte> buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(encoder.GetBytes(        "{\"event\":\"loginBrowser\",\"data\":{\"login\":\"000000003077\",\"data\":\"1\"}}"));
            await webSocket.SendAsync(buffer, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);

            if (webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
            {
                if (ShowMessage.created != true)
                {
                    var dummy = new Control(); // to initialize SynchronizationContext
                    _sync = SynchronizationContext.Current;
                    new Thread(ThreadProc).Start();
                }

                await Receive(webSocket);               
            }

        }

        private static async Task Receive(ClientWebSocket webSocket)
        {
            while (webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
            {
                ArraySegment<Byte> buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new Byte[256]);
                var result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);

                if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
                {
                    await webSocket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, string.Empty,        CancellationToken.None);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (result.EndOfMessage)
                    {
                        message += encoder.GetString(buffer.ToArray());
                        SendMessage(message);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        message += encoder.GetString(buffer.ToArray());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static void ShowFormFromAnotherThread(string text)
        {
            _sync.Post(SendOrPostCallback, text);
        }

        private static void SendOrPostCallback(object state)
        {
            var form = new Notification();
            form.Text = (string)state;
            form.Show();
        }

        private static void ThreadProc()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000); // wait imitation
                ShowFormFromAnotherThread("HI");
            }
        }

         /*Notification is my form and depending on where I put this part:
         var dummy = new Control(); // to initialize SynchronizationContext
        _sync = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        new Thread(ThreadProc).Start();
```

Or i doesn't call login or doesn't enter receive() method or the best case It receives the information
            calls the threadProc and the ShowFormFromAnotherThread but doesn't enter SednOrPostCallBack*/

Comment: It's just a console application?

Comment: It could be nice to show us startup code from Main method.

Comment: It's just a console application at the begin. The Main Method just call the class that connects with websocket and when the connection is made the thread is started

Comment: But of course that, because it uses a form it's a windows form application. Some of the links that I've used:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11995466/c-sharp-calling-form-show-from-another-thread
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549976/how-to-display-a-form-from-another-thread
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleThreadSync
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application.Run(new App());
        }
    }

    public class App : ApplicationContext
    {
        private readonly SynchronizationContext _sync;

        public App()
        {
            var dummy = new Control(); // to initialize SynchronizationContext
            _sync = SynchronizationContext.Current;
            new Thread(ThreadProc).Start();
        }

        public void ShowFormFromAnotherThread(string text)
        {
            _sync.Post(SendOrPostCallback, text);
        }

        private void SendOrPostCallback(object state)
        {
            var form = new Form1();
            form.Text = (string)state;
            form.Show();
        }

        private void ThreadProc()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000); // wait imitation
                ShowFormFromAnotherThread("HI");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that it's a good option, but let me ask you a question: this SendOrPostCallBack can show more than one form, per example, I can add a loop inside of it to .show() more than one form?(Sorry if it looks a silly question)

Comment: SendOrPostCallback calling from a UI thread and you can do anything with UI in this method. 
Try:
 private void SendOrPostCallback(object state)
        {
            var form = new Form1();
            form.Text = (string)state;
            form.Show();

            var form2= new Form2();
            form2.Text = "I am other form!";
            form2.Show();
        }

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try this later, but it looks like it's going to workout good.

Comment: The problem that I'm facing is that as I said I call a websocket using async method to connect, login and receive messages, when I use the _sync to start the thread apparently all the websocket stops working, maybe because it becomes sync, so I don't know what to do to deal with both the sync thread and async websocket.

Comment: It's need to show the actual code. Asyc results itself comes from non-UI threads, from ThreadPool.

Comment: In other hands, it is no matter from which we are call _sync: from manually created thread or from async callback.

Comment: I've added the code in order to you understand better what I'm saying

Answer (score 0):

Try to call this:

```
var dummy = new Control(); // to initialize SynchronizationContext
_sync = SynchronizationContext.Current;
```

from a contructor SocketService() and *not* from async methods. This is an initialization code and it must call *from main thread*.

Comment: Already tried, it tries to execute:
await webSocket.ConnectAsync(new Uri(uri), CancellationToken.None);
and doesn't execute anything more.

Comment: Maybe this is a connectivity problem, not thread synchronization as stated in current question. Try to set breakpoint to the first line of the Login method and check: called this method or not.

Comment: No, it doesn't enter Login method, as I've said previously it calls await webSocket.ConnectAsync(new Uri(uri), CancellationToken.None); 
and stops there, but i don't think is a connectivity problem, because if i put the var dummy = new Control(); // to initialize SynchronizationContext
_sync = SynchronizationContext.Current; where it is shown on the code above the execution occurs normally just doesn't show the form, it even executes the receive method.

Comment: any more ideas, because if I use the Application.DoEvents as shown below the first one's work than the rest stops.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after reading a little bit more, the solution that kind worked out was this one, but the only way of using the 
.show from the notifician is to use the Application.DoEvents and I've been warned from the sources that I've looked into
that this method should not be used, unless is the only option, because It can cause some problems with the Threads and other things.
So unless someone can give me another hint or clue about what to do, I have two options or use this method and try to fix some other bug
that It can cause or use the .showDialog because don't know why It works without any other problem, but to use .showDialog I've 
to use another thread where I create and show the notification because if I don't do, the loop will stop at each iteration
in order to wait the .showDialog be closed. And as it isn't a problem I want to avoid using a lot of threads, because it can cause
another problem with the sync between them:

```
namespace ReiDoCSharp
{
    class ShowMessage
    {
        private static RootObject alerta;
        public static bool created;
        private static int startPosition;

        public static void setStartPosition(int start)
        {
            if (start < startPosition)
            {
                startPosition = start;
            }
        }

        public RootObject getAlerta()
        {
            return ShowMessage.alerta;
        }

        public void setAlerta(RootObject root)
        {
            ShowMessage.alerta = root;
        }

        private static void DoWork()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (created != true)
                {
                    created = true;
                }

                if (alerta != null)
                {
                    string mensagem = "";

                    if ((alerta.data.Informacoes[1] != "") && (alerta.data.Informacoes[1] != null))
                    {
                        mensagem += alerta.data.Informacoes[1];
                    }

                    if ((alerta.data.Informacoes[0] != "") && (alerta.data.Informacoes[0] != null))
                    {
                        mensagem += alerta.data.Informacoes[0];
                    }

                    if (mensagem != "")
                    {
                        startPosition = 5;


                        string[] messages = mensagem.Split(new[] { "<br><br>" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                        foreach (string message in messages)
                        {

                            Notification popup = new Notification();
                            popup.label1.Text = message;
                            popup.TopMost = true;
                            popup.Show();
                            Application.DoEvents();
                            /*Solution with the ShowDialog would be:
                                Task.Run(() => showNotification(message));
                            */
                        }
                    }
                }

                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
        }

        //Then I won't need to use Application.DoEvents, but would have to create more threads
        private static Task showNotification(string message)
        {
            Notification popup = new Notification();
            popup.label1.Text = message;
            popup.TopMost = true;
            popup.ShowDialog();
        }

        public static Task createPopupsAsync()
        {
            Task.Run(() => DoWork());
        }
    }

}

namespace ReiDoCSharp
{
    class SocketService
    {
        private static object consoleLock = new object();
        private const bool verbose = true;
        private static readonly TimeSpan delay = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3000);
        private static UTF8Encoding encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
        private static string message;
        private static RootObject alerta;

        public SocketService()
        {
            Begin();
        }

        public static void Begin()
        {
            alerta = null;

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    Connect("ws://192.168.120.38:9091").Wait();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }
            }
        }

        public static async Task Connect(string uri)
        {
            ClientWebSocket webSocket = null;

            try
            {
                webSocket = new ClientWebSocket();
                await webSocket.ConnectAsync(new Uri(uri), CancellationToken.None);
                await Login(webSocket);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (webSocket != null)
                    webSocket.Dispose();

                lock (consoleLock)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("WebSocket closed.");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                }
            }
        }

        private static async Task Login(ClientWebSocket webSocket)
        {
            ArraySegment<Byte> buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(encoder.GetBytes("{\"event\":\"loginBrowser\",\"data\":{\"OPERADOR\":\"000000003077\",\"NRORG\":\"1\"}}"));
            await webSocket.SendAsync(buffer, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);

            if (webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
            {
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ShowMessage.createPopupsAsync());
                await Receive(webSocket);
            }
        }

        private static async Task Receive(ClientWebSocket webSocket)
        {
            while (webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
            {
                ArraySegment<Byte> buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new Byte[256]);
                var result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);

                if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
                {
                    await webSocket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, string.Empty, CancellationToken.None);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (result.EndOfMessage)
                    {
                        message += encoder.GetString(buffer.ToArray());
                        SendMessage(message);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        message += encoder.GetString(buffer.ToArray());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static void LogStatus(bool receiving, byte[] buffer, int length, string assunto)
        {
            lock (consoleLock)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = receiving ? ConsoleColor.Green : ConsoleColor.Yellow;

                if (verbose)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(encoder.GetString(buffer) + "  " + assunto);
                }

                Console.ResetColor();
            }
        }

        private static void SendMessage(string message)
        {
            message = message.Replace("event", "evento");
            message = message.Replace("\0", "");

            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            RootObject mess = js.Deserialize<RootObject>(message);

            if (mess.data.Informacoes[1] != "")
            {
                mess.data.Informacoes[1] += "<br>";
            }

            if (alerta == null)
            {
                alerta = mess;
            }
            else
            {
                if ((mess.data.Quantidade[0] != 0) && (mess.data.Quantidade == null))
                {
                    if ((mess.data.Quantidade[0] == -1) && (mess.data.Informacoes[0] == ""))
                    {
                        alerta = null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alerta = mess;
                    }
                }
                else if (mess.data.Quantidade[0] == 0)
                {
                    alerta = null;
                }

                if ((mess.data.Quantidade[1] != 0) && (mess.data.Informacoes[1] != ""))
                {
                    alerta = mess;
                }
            }

            new ShowMessage().setAlerta(alerta);
            message = "";
        }

    }
}
```