# Close a form from a thread

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading, c#-4.0

I have a Thread that starts in my main form

```
    private void changePasswordbutton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        waitForm.Show();
        Thread thread = new Thread(ProcessInkPresenter);
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
        thread.Join();
        waitForm.Hide();
        waitForm.Dispose();
    }
```

I want to close the waitForm inside the ProcessInkPresenter method (which is running on a thread) instead of waiting for the thread to complete.

How do I do this?

Thanks

Method signatures

```
private void ProcessInkPresenter()
```

Defined in the class header

```
Wait waitForm;
```

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/a/8443732/555547 work? Not sure about how Thread joining affects that.

Comment: Why are you using a thread here at all? Why not just call ShowDialog on that other form instead?

Comment: Its a very complicated story. I need a thread for using Watin features. The thread parses HTML to see if the password changed. So I need to make the WaitForm disappear if successful. We only know if its successful from inside the thread. I can't use WaitFoorm.Close from inside the thread because .Net won't allow it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original code doesn't make sense.  It shows a form, then starts a thread, then waits for that thread to complete.  If you want the form to be run on it's own UI thread, have `ProcessInkPresenter` run on the same UI thread (which it should if it interacts with the UI) and have the form closed and be disposed of when `ProcessInkPresenter` completes, try this:

```
private void changePasswordbutton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(state => {
            using (var waitForm = new WaitForm()) {
                waitForm.Activated += (s, e) => {
                    ProcessInkPresenter();
                    waitForm.Hide();
                }
                Application.Run(waitForm);
            }
        }
    );
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();
}
```

If the worker thread does not have to interact with the GUI, then what you want is something like the following.  Note that I make use of Invoke to make sure that the interaction with the UI is done *on the UI thread*.  There is no need to check InvokeRequired here, since I already know for sure that I am on a background thread.

If you want to keep the same waitForm instance:

```
private void changePasswordbutton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(state => {
            try {
                ProcessInkPresenter();

                // If ProcessInkPresenter fails, this line will never execute
                waitForm.Invoke(new Action(()=>waitForm.Hide()));
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                // You probably want to do something with ex here,
                // rather than just swallowing it.
            }
        });
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();
    waitForm.Show();
}
```

**NOTE:** It doesn't make sense to dispose your WaitForm if you have a single instance of it (your `Wait` instance).  Either construct an instance each time you use it, or never dispose it and use `.Hide()` instead.

Comment: Basically this is what I am trying to achieve. The user clicks the button. I display a Form (called waitForm) and size it to the width and height of the screen. The wait form displays a message while the thread does it's own thing. If the thread finishes successfully, I want the waitForm to disappear and only leave the ResultForm on screen. (ResultForm is created within the thread).

Comment: Does the background process need to interact with the GUI in any way?

Comment: The background process opens up IE and then starts parsing HTML. It doesn't have anything to do with the GUI. If the results are positive/negative, we launch a new Form that displays the results.

Comment: See my second example, just added.

Comment: ProcessInkPresenter is a void function. Here is the method headers (updated above in question)

Comment: Wait is the name of my WinForm. I declare it in code via Wait waitForm. In the Load method, I do waitForm = new Wait(); and continue setting up the properties for wait (text to display while background thread is doing it's thing)

Comment: Your code never really executes the ProcessInkPresenter method. The code for ProcessInkPresenter takes upto 5 min to execute so the Wait Form is an Overlay to prevent the user from doing other things while the application is running.

Comment: That doesn't make sense either- see the note at the end of my answer.  I also updated the second example with the ***assumption*** (since you didn't actually say how you define success in `ProcessInkPresenter`) that throwing an exception defines failure, and not throwing an exception defines success.

Comment: There was a bug in it, yeah.  Try that last example, should be straight now.

Comment: The wait form doesn't go away unless the form thats started from ProcessInkPresenter is closed.

Comment: Of course it doesn't. If `ProcessInkPresenter` **opens a form** and **doesnt return until the form is closed** then you need to modify `ProcessInkPresenter` to close the form that **it** opened.

Comment: I thought the whole idea of a Thread is to run independently from the Main thread. If I spawn a Thread and open / close forms. I expect that the code on the Main thread would continue to run.

Comment: It does.  The code that I demonstrate above links the closing of the form to the completion of your `ProcessInkPresenter` method.  **If your `ProcessInkPresenter` doesn't exit, how could my code possibly know when to close the form?**

Comment: I have 3 Forms. The mainForm, WaitForm and ResultForm. The MainForm has a button and that is suppose to launch WaitForm (which tells the user to wait while we process some HTML pages). When the results are processed, we would then throw up the ResultForm and make the WaitForm dissappear (at the same time)

Comment: I can modify the ProcessInkPresenter so it becomes a bool and then return true when the results are ready. I don't know if that will help